# How to avoid onclick to work again after selecting option in html-select?

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-select

I have problem in the following code;

```js
function check(x){
  //do staff here
}
```

```html
<select onclick="check(this)" class="form-control">
  <option value="value1">1</option>
  <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>

<select onclick="check(this)" class="form-control">
  <option value="value1">1</option>
  <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>
```

When i click on the select tag, my function works but after selecting an option, the function works again.
But i want the function to work only when i click on the select tag, not when selecting one of the options tag again.
I searched but couldn't find any solution for this. How can i avoid this to happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - HTML <select> onclick Event triggered when clicking the down button of the scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186338/javascript-html-select-onclick-event-triggered-when-clicking-the-down-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `flag` on first execution and check the flag.

```js
var executed = {};
function check(e) {
  var name = e.name;
  if (!executed[e.name]) {
    executed[e.name] = true;
    console.log("executed", e.name);
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="select1" onclick="check(this)" class="form-control">
  <option value="value1">1</option>
  <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" onclick="check(this)" class="form-control">
  <option value="value1">1</option>
  <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works fine when there is just one select tag, but i have more than one.I edited the question.

Comment: updated answer according to your requirement. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Use `onchange` instead of `onclick`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

```
<select onchange="check(this.value)" class="form-control">
  <option value="value1">1</option>
  <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want it to work only for one time, don't want anything to happen after selecting and option.

Comment: I see. You have to store somewhere that first click has already been triggered

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can use the one() function as it is documented [here](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$( "select" ).one('change', function(){
    //do staff here
}
```

---

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="value1">1</option>
    <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control">
    <option value="value1">1</option>
    <option value="value2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s check the event.stopPropagation() method.